# Is there a way to set two starting and stoping points in range() in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

```
for i in range(65, 123)
```

I want i to range from 65 to 91 and from 97 to 123 (ASCII for upper and lower case letters) omitting 92 to 96, but I can only input one start and one stop value. Is there a way to omit those or set diferent start and stop values?

Comment: @KevinW. It's a duplicate, but that question is explicitly about Python2 while this one is about Python 3. At the very least, the return values and function names are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *chain* the two range objects using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> chain(range(5), range(9, 14))
<itertools.chain object at 0x101a8e588>
>>> list(_)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

---

```
 from itertools import chain

 for i in chain(range(65, 91), range(97, 123)):
     ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.chain(range(65, 92), range(97, 123)):
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list(range(65,92)) + list(range(97,124))
```

will output:

```
[65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use 'magic numbers' in your code. If 65 is the ASCII code for 'A', say so: `ord('A')`. Second, you can combine two lists into one list and iterate over it:

```
for i in list(range(ord('A'),ord('Z')+1)) + list(range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)):
```